# Variable quotation marks

Tags: variables, batch-file, quotes

In a for loop it requires quotes around the string to recall the entire length (Of the folder) but this causes problems later on in the script. Is there any way to remove the quotation marks simply (Such as :~1,-1 used in the echo)?

```
@ECHO OFF

set ICOINI=Desktop.ini

for /D /R "%cd%" %%d IN (*) do (call :Write_File "%%~nd")

Pause

goto End_File

:Write_File

set FOLDER=%1

if /I %FOLDER%==Icon goto :EOF
if /I %FOLDER%==Extras goto :EOF

echo %FOLDER:~1,-1%

goto :EOF

:End_File
```

Comment: You can use the tilde `~` to remove double quotes: `set "FOLDER=%~1"`

Comment: @Endoro I have tried changing the set FOLDER but to no avail, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Endoro.  Perhaps are times when there are spaces in %1.  To accomodate that you should make these changes:

```
set "FOLDER=%~1"

if /I "%FOLDER%"=="Icon" goto :EOF
if /I "%FOLDER%"=="Extras" goto :EOF

echo %FOLDER%
```

Comment: Thank you and @Endoro, I tried this myself and it didn't seem to work. I guess I must of made a typo.